# Вывести часть содержимого с чужого сайта на свой

Tags: php, curl

Есть сайт, на котором отображается количество заражённых коронавирусом.

https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6

У меня вопрос. Можно ли на свой сайт выводить как-нибудь это число? Может быть, с помощью curl

Comment: Можно с помощью отличной библиотеки phpQuery.
Ею легко пользваться, так как методы такие же как и в jquery

Comment: Спасибо. А не подскажете более конкретно, что использовать с предоставленных этой библиотекой возможностей для реализации моей задачи?

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/KKpQgQw

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле на сайте который вы указали количество указано svg картинкой.
А данные она нятет по ссылке ниже. 
Думаю разберетесь как получить даные из Json ("features":[{"attributes":{"value":9776}}]})

https://services1.arcgis.com/0MSEUqKaxRlEPj5g/arcgis/rest/services/ncov_cases/FeatureServer/1/query?f=json&where=1%3D1&returnGeometry=false&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=*&outStatistics=%5B%7B%22statisticType%22%3A%22sum%22%2C%22onStatisticField%22%3A%22Confirmed%22%2C%22outStatisticFieldName%22%3A%22value%22%7D%5D&outSR=102100&cacheHint=true

Comment: Спасибо. Скажите пожалуйста, а как вы нашли эту ссылку?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете даже примерно так сделать

```
    $str = file_get_contents('https://ru.vuejs.org/');
    $startStr = '<a class="button white" href="/v2/guide/">';
    $startEnd = '</a>';
    //Обрезаем все после 
    $result = substr($str, strpos($str, $startStr) + strlen($startStr), strlen($str));
    //Обрезаем все до
    $result = substr($result, 0, strpos($result, $startEnd));

    echo $result;
```

Но желательно хранить результат либо в кеше либо еще где. И обновлят через определенный промежуток времети нак как "file_get_contents()" будет каждый раз дергать другой сайт и дожидаться ответа.